# Facebook IOS Sdk find all friends ids

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for doing a tableview which allow you to select one facebook friends and be able to send him a message to his wall later. The thing is that i tried /me/friends but it returns only the friends which use the same app...and it's not really usefull then.

I also tried /me/taggable_friends but it returns me an id for tag the friend and doesn't work for sending a message...

The last one i didn't try is /me/invitable_friends since it's not a game...but i guess it's also using an id only for invitation...

So is there a way to get the list of all the friends of facebook and get there ids ?

thanks !

Comment: No you can not get all friends. I would suggest using the share dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't supported anymore. There doesn't appear to be a simple way to grab all of a user's friends. You could use `/user/invitablefriends`, but that comes with a whole host of caveats. From the docs:

> A list of friends that can be invited to install a Facebook game.
>
> The Invitable Friends API is only available to apps classified as Games, which also have a Canvas presence. This API is not available in v1.0. It may be called by mobile games as long as they also have a Canvas presence.
>
> The Invitable Friends API is only available to apps classified as Games, which also have a Canvas presence. This API is not available in v1.0. It may be called by mobile games as long as they also have a Canvas presence.
> Since Graph API v2.0, /me/friends returns a person's friends who also use the app. You may use the Requests Dialog to invite people to play a game. However, if you want to build a custom multi-friend selector within your game, you need to use call /me/invitable_friends which returns a ranked list of a person's friends who do not play the game, along with a token which can be passed to the Request Dialog in order to invite them. Read our guide on using the Invitable Friends API.

Additionally, posting to another user's wall cannot be done through the Facebook SDK anymore. You can post to your own wall and you can tag other users, but you can't post directly to their wall anymore.

Comment: In API v2.0 /user/friendlists will only return the name of the lists. Not the friends in them.

Comment: @WizKid Correct, to clarify, you can get the individual lists, then use /{friendlist-id}/members to get the members of each list. Adding clarification above. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/friendlist/members

Comment: And if you look at the top of that page it say it isn't available in v2.0